# Graceful way to find combinations in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I'm looking for combinations, not permutations, and have found some really great examples ranging from using `flatMap` such as https://stackoverflow.com/a/54329187/669843

The result of `['a', 'b', 'c']` would be an array of arrays of 3 (a, b, and c). The result I'm looking for would also contain arrays of length 1 and 2.

Example:

```
['a']
['b']
['c']
['a', 'b']
['a', 'b', 'c']
['a', 'c']
...
```

I'm accomplishing the results with something like this but this seems extraordinarily awful and requires de-duplication.

```
for(let i = 0; tci < combo.length; tci++) {
  let newcombo = [allitems[item]].concat(combo.slice(tci, combo.length));
  ...
  push newcombo;
```

Comment: Wonder why this off topic?  It has running code and wonders how to make it better?

Comment: @charles, because the code shown for review is a couple of lines with absolutely no context (there's stuff obviously missing in the mysterious `...` region, and variables `combo`, `item` and `tci` appear out of nowhere).  There's clearly quite a bit that's missing before this function is reviewable.

Comment: I understand! Thanks. I was trying to be brief but I'm going to give it a few passes and resubmit later, @TobySpeight

Answer (score -2):

You can write this better.  The best way to explain it is to see the code example in [Python's itertools module](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations):

```
def combinations(iterable, r):
    # combinations('ABCD', 2) --> AB AC AD BC BD CD
    # combinations(range(4), 3) --> 012 013 023 123
    pool = tuple(iterable)
    n = len(pool)
    if r > n:
        return
    indices = list(range(r))
    yield tuple(pool[i] for i in indices)
    while True:
        for i in reversed(range(r)):
            if indices[i] != i + n - r:
                break
        else:
            return
        indices[i] += 1
        for j in range(i+1, r):
            indices[j] = indices[j-1] + 1
        yield tuple(pool[i] for i in indices)
```

This generates the combinations of length 'r' efficiently using counting.  You can create all combinations by either adding length-1 'nulls' to the pool or just iterating over the lengths.

Combination generation is a bit hard to grok, and really you should step through this example until you get it.  It's a variation on the idea of manually counting used throughout many algorithms.

The base idea for combinations('ABCD', 2) is to start with 'AB' (first `yield`), increment the last letter 'AC' then 'AD' with the `for j` loop doing nothing, on the next loop i will be the index 0, so 'A' -> 'B' and the second resets to one more than the first character and you yield 'BC'.

Trace the code.  Keep hacking!  Keep notes.

Comment: That's a pretty good example. It definitely can be better, but one of the points I was trying to make was a more graceful way of doing it. In the itertools example you have a very nice generator. Is a JavaScript generator a suggestion? I really want to avoid the while with a for, etc, which is where I am now.

Comment: A simpler way to iterate all combinations of all lengths is to see that each element may be either absent or present.  There's a natural mapping to binary numbers of length `n` (start from 0 or 1 depending on whether you want to include the empty set as a result).

Comment: The question is tagged [tag:Javascript]. The consensus is that [answers should use the same language as the code in the question](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2631/120114). Also Please note, questions involving stub code are off-topic on this site. If OP edits their post to address the problem and make their post on-topic, they make your answer moot. [It is advised not to answer such questions](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6389/120114). Protip: There are many on-topic questions to answer; you'll make more reputation faster if you review code in on-topic questions.

Comment: Sigh.  Everytime I write an answer the 'this how we should do it here' folks come out.   I only rarely write answers now.

Comment: @TobySpeight  Very nice insight!  So just mapping the range of numbers `pow(2, combo.length)` through `string(2)` for binary and tuples of matching number.  Very slick.